# constructor in UML sequence diagram

Tags: constructor, uml, sequence-diagram

what is the meaning of the following sequence diagram and exactly the constructor(that is represented as a create object)?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that `ClassA` instantiates `ClassB`. The arrow represents that the constructor of `ClassB` is called by `ClassA`

Comment: I am not sure what is troubling you.Class A calls `new ClassB()`.Is this clearer?

Comment: how can we represent this call in programming language such as Java?

Comment: Like this:`ClassB theClass = new ClassB();`.This creates an instance of class B

Comment: i did know how to create an instance of class but i really like to know how  ClassA instantiates ClassB in the diagram as written in java for example?

Comment: @Chriss What don't you understand? That's how ClassA instantiates a ClassB.

Comment: thank you @DaveNewton i don't understand this call between two lifelines

Comment: @DaveNewton  instantiation means create object form class but here there is two object and each one of them instantiated by their classes??

Comment: @Chriss All it says that a ClassA instantiates a ClassB. I don't undertand the confusion.

Answer (score 4):

The message's name "Class B()" is wrong : it should be "create".
Is that what confusing you ?

Answer (score 2):

Chriss, hopefully you've figured it out by now.

Here is an example in Java:

**Main.java**

```java
package com.example.umlquestion;

// (e.g. your application that makes and uses an instance of ClassA)
public class Main {
    public Main() {
        // this calls ClassA's constructor, which will then call ClassB's constructor
        private ClassA instanceA = new ClassA(); 
        // ...
    }
}
```

**ClassA.java**

```java
package com.example.umlquestion;

public class ClassA  {
    private ClassB instanceB;
    public ClassA() {
        instanceB = new ClassB();
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```

**ClassB.java**

```java
package com.example.umlquestion;

public class ClassB  {
    public ClassB() {
        // ...
    }
    // ...
}
```