# object instantiate another object?

Tags: java, object, instantiation, uml

is it possible to instantiate object from another object
look at this
 [constructor in UML sequence diagram](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15012587/constructor-in-uml-sequence-diagram)

Does this situation possible in programming language such as Java?

Does this situation possible in modeling language such as UML?

Comment: You're asking if you can instantiate an object from another object in Java? Considering that every program requires an object, I sure hope so.

Comment: On your second question, you are essentially asking whether this example in UML can be expressed in UML.  It's hard to see how the answer could be other than "yes".  I think you need to clarify the question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the whole concept of Object-Orientated Programming depends on objects being able to create other objects.

In Java we create instances by calling a constructor such as `new ClassB()` which instantiates a new ClassB object for us. If we wanted to have ClassA instantiate ClassB the we simply need to make ClassA call ClassB's constructor. Here's how we'd do it in Java

```
public class ClassA{
    public ClassA(){
        ClassB instance1 = new ClassB();
    }
}
```

Here I've made it so that when **ClassA** is instantiated (has it's constructor called) it creates a new instance of **ClassB** called *instance1*.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, yes, you can do this via inheritance or composition.

Inheritance:

```
ClassB extends ClassA {
    public ClassB() {
        super();    // calls ClassA constructor
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

Composition:

```
ClassX {
    private ClassY y;
    public ClassX() {
        y = new ClassY();    // calls ClassY constructor
        // do more stuff
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: I wouldn't agree with the first.  In the UML diagram there are two objects. In VikingSteve's code, only one object is created.  My understanding is that it's not good UML to draw 2 lifelines for one object even though there are two classes involved.

Comment: Then yes, you're right, the second example would be more appropriate :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is an essential part of Java, and any object oriented a language.

If you have two objects, A and B, and B is a subclass of A, you can instantiate A using B:

```
A baseObject = new B();
```

The relationship here denotes that 'B' IS A 'A': meaning anywhere you have an A, you can instantiate a B in it's place, because B is a proper subtype of A.  Note then you can still only use A's interface if you use it like this.

A real life example in Java can be seen when using a list.  the List class in Java is an abstract container type derived from Collection.  List, in this example, is our 'A' type.  There are many different kinds of lists, such as LinkedList and ArrayList.  LinkedList and ArrayList are proper subtypes of List and are type 'B' in this example.  So you can initialize a List as any of its subtypes:

```
List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

or

```
List<String> stringList = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Hopefully this is of some help.